# I dont understand how this code sort this python list(), and how to reproduce it in C++ with a vector

Tags: python, c++

I have a C++ vector that i need to sort like this python list:

```
sorted(self.weirdest, key=lambda tup: (tup[0], tup[-1]))
self.weirdest.sort(key=lambda elem: abs(elem[1]))
self.weirdest.reverse()
```

But i dont understand what is it doing, can someone explain to me please, thanks.

ps: it's a list of weirdest temperatures values if it can help.

Comment: Do you have any specific question? Like this the question is too broad.

Comment: Could you add an example input and expected output to your question? Edit: I guess sorted is this one (not something self-written?):https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_sorted.asp

Comment: yes, what does the sorted(self.weirdest, key=lambda tup: (tup[0], tup[-1])) do and self.weirdest.sort(key=lambda elem: abs(elem[1])) do please

Comment: sorted is going to consider first and last item of any element in the list to be sorted for sorting.But you need to store it as sorted returns a new list and sort is in place sorting.

Answer (score 0):

First line doesn't do anything. It returns a sorted list which is discarded.

Second line sorts the list by the absolute value of the second element in each entry.

Last line reverses the list.

In C++ something like this would work:

```
std::sort(weirdest.begin(), weirdest.end(), 
          [](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
             return abs(a[1]) < abs(b[1]);
          });

std::reverse(weirdest.begin(), weirdest.end());
```

Comment: And if you use `>` instead of `<` to compare, you can skip that final reversing.

Comment: @Shawn I wanted to keep close to the python code. You could also pass reverse=True in python to get the same result.

Comment: can't seem to do that, my vector is a std::vector<std::pair<float, float>> , i got on the line     [](const auto &a, const auto &b)) { : error: void value was not ignored as it should have been

Comment: use `.second` for pairs.

Comment: Off-Topic: Is using `std::sort` a good practice? Or we should use our own?

Comment: @FarbodAhmadian Always prefer existing libraries when available. To consider writing your own you need a) evidence that the change will significantly improve something;b) good reasoning why the existing solution doesn't give you good performance.

Comment: @FarbodAhmadian Writing your own ads significant complexity to your code and potentially new bugs.